# How to toggle item in custom layout of activeprensentation/activeslide via VBA in PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How can I toggle (`set .visible = true/false`) an item (`shade`), which is defined in the custom layout/master layout?

Example:
I have an item named "TEST1" in my custom layout number 3
I have several slides in my custom layout, so I need to get the number of the used custom layout first.. because the VBA must run on all slides..
I tried:

```
ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex).Shapes("TEST1").Visible = msoFalse
```

But this does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the custom layout for a given slide, use this:

```
Option Explicit

' ***********************************************************
' Purpose:  Hide & Show a shape on the slide's custom layout.
'           Works in and out of slide show mode.
'           Change the constant sShapeName as required.
' Inputs:   None.
' Outputs:  None.
' Author:   Jamie Garroch
' Company:  YOUpresent Ltd. http://youpresent.co.uk/
' ***********************************************************
Sub ToggleCustomLayoutObject()
  Const sShapeName = "TEST1"
  Dim oSld As Slide
  If SlideShowWindows.Count = 0 Then
    Set oSld = ActivePresentation.Slides(ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex)
  Else
    Set oSld = ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex)
  End If
  With oSld.CustomLayout
    .Shapes(sShapeName).Visible = Not .Shapes(sShapeName).Visible
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, that does not work - the Shape "TEST1" is still visible, if I click on a button, which uses your code above.  This works:  ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(6).Shapes("TEST1").Visible = msoFalse

Comment: Ah. A button equals slide show mode! Code updated to support both normal view and slide show view.